# Trouble with Rewrite or Redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I have a question. Can I change my URL like this using the .htaccess file?:

xxx.es/whatevever/login

www.yyy.es/whatever/login

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in `xxx.es` with root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^ http://www.yyy.es%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

If the site is in the same server add (below `RewriteEngine on`):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?xxx\.es$
```